# Building for the provided.al2 AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to do my source code building for the `provided.al2` AWS Lambda, and I'm wondering what's the best way to do that.

From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-image.html#go-image-al2), it says,

> You can use one image, such as a Go base image, to compile your code and build the executable binary. You can then use a different image, such as provided.al2, in the final FROM statement to define the image that you deploy to Lambda.

However, such practice of building with one image and used provided.al2 as final image doesn't work for me, as I'm build C code and what I got was:

```
/lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found
```

I.e., the AWS provided.al2 Lambda is using glibc 2.26, while I was building with 3+ years old ubuntu:20.04 and am still unable to satisfy its glibc requirement. And *even the 5+ years old ubuntu:18.04* still unable to satisfy its glibc requirement.

I tried to do my build within the [provided.al2](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images/blob/provided.al2/Dockerfile.provided.al2) docker image before writing the Docker file, but found it is impossible to do that -- there is no way to overide the "/lambda-entrypoint.sh":

`entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument`

So, what's the best way to do source code building for the `provided.al2` AWS Lambda?